# Custom annotation to validate string against enum type

Tags: java, validation, enums, annotations, hibernate-validator

I am trying to write a custom annotation that would validate a `String` against a specific `Enum`. I am using `Hibernate Validator API`. The desired use-case would look like follows.

```
@MessageTypeOf(MessageType.NETWORK)
private String message;
```

The `String` should be validated against the value given from the `toString()` method of the enum given as the enum argument (in this case, `MessageType.NETWORK`).

I have written a validator and looks like this.

```
public class MessageTypeValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MessageTypeOf, String> {

    private Set<String> values;

    @Override
    public void initialize(MessageTypeOf constraintAnnotation) {
        values = Arrays.asList(MessageType.values())
                .stream()
                .map(v -> v.toString())
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String s, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        if (s == null) return false;

        return values.contains(s);
    }
}
```

And the annotation.

```
@Target({ FIELD, METHOD, PARAMETER, ANNOTATION_TYPE, TYPE_USE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = MessageTypeValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface MessageTypeOf {

    String message() default "{org.hibernate.validator.referenceguide.chapter06.CheckCase." +
            "message}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default { };

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };

    MessageType value();

    @Target({ FIELD, METHOD, PARAMETER, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    @Documented
    @interface List {
        MessageType[] value();
    }
}
```

However, this would validate if a string is part of the enum (any value), where as I need to validate against a specific one. Could someone suggest how to do that?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just using the enum as the field type directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, basically, the only valid value of the property would be `MessageType.NETWORK.toString()`, is that right? That's quite strange (expecting the client to provide a string that can only have one valid value), but anyway, you just need to check that:

```
public class MessageTypeValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MessageTypeOf, String> {

    private String validValue;

    @Override
    public void initialize(MessageTypeOf constraintAnnotation) {
        this.validValue = constraintAnnotation.value().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String s, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        return this.validValue.equals(s);
    }
}
```